# Where do the parameters come from when interfaces are automatically-implemented?

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism

Using Eclipse, I decided to implement an `interface`.  Eclipse generates the method signatures automatically.

Some of the methods from the interface have parameters passed into the method.  Where do these parameters come from?  They are not in the interface I am implementing, right?

For example, when implementing the `ActionListener` interface, we are forced to implement this method:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
...
}
```

Where is the `ActionEvent` object coming from?

Answer (score 4):

> Now, where do these parameters come from? They certainly are not in the Interface that I am implementing, right?

Actually, wrong. They *are* part of the interface that you're implementing.

Let's take `ActionListener` as an example. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html#actionPerformed%28java.awt.event.ActionEvent%29):

```
void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Ok, but can you tell me what is calling my implementation of actionPerformed and where the ActionEvent object is coming from?

Answer (score 3):

An interface definition in Java can be thought of more like a contract or promise than anything else. By claiming to implement an interface, a class is promising that it will have an implementation for the methods defined within. For example, a class implementing `ActionListener` promises to provide an implementation for a method `actionPerformed`, which returns nothing and which requires an `ActionEvent` object to be passed into the method.

Only when the method is called by some other class does the `ActionEvent` object need to exist and pass in. In the interface definition and in the class's implementation, it merely assumes that an `ActionEvent` will be passed in. That's all. It's the exact same as any other method taking in a parameter-- the caller must provide the data in question, and the method simply makes use of it.

As for why `actionPerformed` requires an `ActionEvent`, that can be answered on two different levels:

1. Because the interface definition for `ActionListener` mandates it by requiring that exact method signature. (This is the "why won't it compile if I don't" answer.)
2. Because the Java API designers, who created the interface, decided that that's how the interface should work. (It makes sense, because `ActionListener` is supposed to listen for "action events", so it's only natural that an object with the action event's information should be passed in. It is the responsibility of the implementing class to act on the information provided. This is the "why did they make it this particular way" answer.)

What's the point of all of this? The answer is [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming): In the case of `ActionListener`, it is possible to register a whole group of `ActionListeners` with different implementations with a Swing component, and all of them can be invoked the same way since they all are guaranteed to have a method `void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`. This means that the Swing component can only worry about the interface (what the behavior is expected to be) of each listener, rather than the implementation (how that behavior actually works and/or how to invoke it).

Comment: Thanks for the response - my question remains I think...             you say "That's all. It's the exact same as any other method taking in a parameter-- the caller must provide the data in question." Yeah but what is calling my actionPerformed method? I don't see it. Do you? This goes for other inferfaces where the method is magically called and a parameter magically appears.

Comment: Methods aren't magically called and parameters don't magically appear. Take a look at this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html In Java Swing, you can register action listeners on components, and in doing so, you are promised that, when an action event occurs (usually meaning a button is clicked, etc.), that any `ActionListener` objects registered with that component will have their `actionPerformed` method invoked, and an `ActionEvent` describing the event is created and passed in at that time.

Answer (score 2):

ActionEvent here is what *needs* to be supplied to actionPerformed,  it says so [here in the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html)

Much of programming is using pre-existing tools.  i.e if I want to make a tic-tac-toe game, where you click around - i have to use ActionEvent or java.MATH

Comment: Let me revise the question - where is the ActionEvent object coming from and more importantly what is calling my implementation of the actionPerformed method?